# Preserve the attributes of a document tag

Tags: xml, xslt

I have this XML below that I use as input

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Document xmlns="some:urn" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <People>
    <Personal>
      <Name>Juan Dela Cruz</Name>
      <Age>21</Age>
    </Personal>
    <Employment>
      <Start>21-02-2014</Start>
      <EmpNumber>1234</EmpNumber>
      <IDNumber></IDNumber>
    </Employment>
    <Personal>
      <Name>Anna Dela Cruz</Name>
      <Age>23</Age>
    </Personal>
    <Employment>
      <Start>21-02-2014</Start>
      <EmpNumber>1235</EmpNumber>
      <IDNumber>1235</IDNumber>
    </Employment>
  </People>
</Document>
```

ANd when I try to transofrm it using this XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:copy-of select="Document"/>
    <Document xmlns="some:urn" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="Document/People" />
    </Document>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match ="People">
    <People>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="Personal" />
      <xsl:apply-templates select="Employment" />
    </People>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Personal">
    <Name>
      <xsl:value-of select ="Personal/Name/." />
    </Name>
    <Age>
      <xsl:value-of select ="Personal/Age/." />
    </Age>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Employment">
    <Start>
      <xsl:value-of select ="Employment/Start/." />
    </Start>
    <EmpNumber>
      <xsl:value-of select ="Employment/EmpNumber/." />
    </EmpNumber>
    <IDNumber>
      <xsl:value-of select ="Employment/IDNumber/." />
    </IDNumber>
  </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I only get this result:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Document xmlns="some:urn" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" />
```

I need a result like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Document xmlns="some:urn" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <People>
    <Personal>
      <Name>Juan Dela Cruz</Name>
      <Age>21</Age>
    </Personal>
    <Employment>
      <Start>21-02-2014</Start>
      <EmpNumber>1234</EmpNumber>
    </Employment>
    <Personal>
      <Name>Anna Dela Cruz</Name>
      <Age>23</Age>
    </Personal>
    <Employment>
      <Start>21-02-2014</Start>
      <EmpNumber>1235</EmpNumber>
      <IDNumber>1235</IDNumber>
    </Employment>
  </People>
</Document>
```

Anyone have an Idea what is wrong with my XSLT, I am using Visual Studio to transform the XML

TIA :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to take namespace in the input XML into account, all your match patterns and select expressions like `Document` or `People` match respectively select elements of those names in no namespace while your input elements are in a namespace. So declare a namespace prefix in your stylesheet for the namespace used in the input and use that prefix in match patterns and XPath expressions to qualify elements names:

```
<xsl:stylesheet
  xmlns:df="some:urn"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  version="1.0">
```

then use e.g. `match="df:People"`, `select="df:Personal"` and so on. But you haven't really told us which transformation result you want, currently it is not clear which changes the transformation needs to make at all on the input.

Based on your edited question and the sample you want as the result all you need is

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

   <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="*[not(*) and not(normalize-space())]"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

that will simply copy all nodes unchanged but suppress copying of empty element nodes like `<IDNumber></IDNumber>`.

Comment: My expected result is something like the XML input but of course it would be trimmed down to those that only have data, my main problem right now is that it fails to transform when there are attributes in the <document> tag of the input XML, but when I removed those attributes it transforms normally.

Comment: The namespace declaration `xmlns="some:urn"` puts all the input elements in that namespace `some:urn` and you need to take that into account as suggested in my response.

Comment: Please edit your question and provide the result sample you want to create with your XSLT for the input sample you have shown.

Comment: @zyberjock, I have edited my answer with complete stylesheet that should create the result you want.

Comment: Hi Martin, thank you for the help youre giving me, but the actual XML has more information so I need to create a XSLT to remove data that is not relevant or add a hardcoded data to the output, that is why I want to solve it in my XSLT. :)

Comment: Well I have already shown how to declare a prefix for the namespace and told you to use e.g. `<xsl:apply-templates select="df:Document/df:People" />` instead of `<xsl:apply-templates select="Document/People" />` and `match="df:People"` instead of `match ="People"`. Make the same change for all other path expressions and match patterns and you should have code that at least finds and processes elements in your input sample. Other than that I can't help because I fail to see why you need all those templates for the simple transformation you want.

Comment: great it worked :), just dont understand it previously, sorry bout that, and thanks