# Getting the value of an attribute in XML using xsl

Tags: xml, xslt

I have xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<report xmlns="http://somesite.com">
<status id1="666" id2="555">Accepted</status>
</report>
```

How can I get the value of id1?
I've tried:

```
<xsl:value-of select="report/status/@mid" />
<xsl:value-of select="status/@mid" />                   
<xsl:value-of select="@mid" />
```

but nothing work. I think there is some problem in path to id1

Comment: Try adding a / at the start of your `select`s, just to see. As far as I remember, I always used it in my XSLs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well why should `@mid` work for attributes named `id1` or `id2`. So use `//@id1`. If you want to write a full path including the elements then you need to take the namespace into account.

Comment: sorry, I've just renamed mid to id1.

Comment: As I said, `//@id1` should suffice. If you want to address the elements then see the first part of the answer in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24648652/preserve-the-attributes-of-a-document-tag/24648864#24648864 on how to take the namespace into account.

Comment: thanks! It works. The problem was in double slash. I wrote / instead of //